# Squid proxy_protocol_access with dstdomain acl

Tags: proxy, squid, access-control-list, filter

I'm configuring a squid proxy to work as a sort of a gateway for traffic egress.
The environment in which this is deployed has a client that makes a request through a load balancer which then sends it on to the squid proxy.
To not obfuscate the original client ip the load balancer uses the proxy protocol.
Squid (3.5+) "supports" the proxy protocol and allows it to be used in an acl.
A working configuration that I have seen to allow proxy protocol access is below:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
http_port 3128 require-proxy-header
http_port 3128
proxy_protocol_access allow localnet
```

However this doesn't allow me to filter the subsequent requests based on dstdomain. I've also tried

```
acl allowed dstdomain .google.com
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
http_port 3128 require-proxy-header
http_port 3128
proxy_protocol_access allow localnet allowed
```

But this causes my curl requests to return with error 53 empty requests.
I've tried

```
acl allowed dstdomain .google.com
http_port 3128 require-proxy-header
http_port 3128
proxy_protocol_access allow allowed
```

This has the same behavior as the one directly above. I've tried also

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
http_port 3128 require-proxy-header
http_port 3128
proxy_protocol_access allow localnet

acl allowed dstdomain .google.com
http_access allow allowed
http_access deny all
```

And this results in all the traffic being allowed out. (I've also tried swapping those 2 blocks as well with the same results.

Am I missing something? Does someone have a working configuration that allows for domain filtering *and* proxy protocol?

Answer (score 3):

After looking at this more, I was able to fix the config so it would work.
This works:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
http_port 3128 require-proxy-header
http_port 3128
proxy_protocol_access allow localnet

acl allowed dstdomain .google.com .yahoo.com
http_access allow allowed
http_access deny all
```

Although I had tried this before, I was running into a snag with an `http_access deny all` was listed above.

The proxy_protocol_access simply establishes where the proxy protocol can be accepted from. In looking at the cache.log on reload, it seems to indicate that any dstdomain filtering in proxy_protocol_access is not actually allowed.

As a note: The rules are applied in order of appearance in the configuration and as things match they are applied. So if a deny appears above, the request is denied.

Additional logging information can be provided for troubleshooting using the `debug_options` specifically `debug_options 3,28` for configuration file troubleshooting. (More info here: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/DebugSections)

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/proxy_protocol_access/

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but for those working with Squid as a forward proxy (i.e. egress to internet), with load balancers between Squid and your workload, you may want to try it out this way.

I had issues with finding out my client IP addresses at Squid forward proxy when the clients were behind an AWS Network Load Balancer. Instead, the NLB's IP addresses were being logged and detected at the Squid forward proxy, causing problems with my domain filtering.

To solve this, I enabled Proxy Protocol for both the NLB and Squid.

**In the Squid Config:**

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/20
acl loadbalancers src 10.0.16.0/27 10.0.16.32/27
```

Where localnet is your vpc or subnet, where your workload is hosted. And loadbalancers are the IPs of your NLB. If you are using AWS NLB, enable Proxy Protocol V2, this will append the proxy protocol header to the request - informing downstream servers to look out for your client IP addresses.

```
http_port 3128 require-proxy-header
#http_port <some-other-port-if-required>
```

For your http listener port and mode, just declare it once for this port. You need the mode require-proxy-header as squid will then look out for the client IPs behind the load balancer. If you expose the same port twice, you'd get a duplicate listener error in the access logs.

```
proxy_protocol_access allow loadbalancers
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/proxy_protocol_access/), you need to declare this with when require-proxy-header mode is enabled. Essentially saying that your load balancers are proxies and will be sending out a proxy header, look out for client IP.

```
acl mydomains dstdomain .google.com .yahoo.com
http_access allow mydomains localnet
http_access deny all
```

Business as usual, setting ACL mapping of desired destination URLs to be accessed or blocked from your localnet resources.